What do we call this pattern in functions?
There is a common pattern in math where we take a function of interest and some more standard function(s) and then show that these functions are “commutative.” For example, with the limit of a sequence and arithmetic operations, we have;

Scalar multiple of a limit:  The limit of a constant times a sequence is the constant times the limit.
Sum of limits: The limit of the sum of two sequences is the sum of their limits.
Product of limits: The limit of the product of two sequences is the product of their limits.
Quotient of limits: The limit of the quotient of two sequences is the quotient of their limits (if the
denominator limit is non-zero).

I say “commutative” because I can’t point to the two specific functions that would actually possess commutativity, but nonetheless these equalities still seem to involve functions with some sort of order-reversing property. For example, in $1$, it seems we can express this as
$f \circ g_1 = g_2 \circ f,$ where
$f(x_n) = \text{lim}(x_n),$$ g_1(c,(x_n)) = c(x_n), $ and $g_2(c,L) = cL,$ and even though $g_1$ is on sequences and numbers and $g_2$ is just on numbers, it doesn’t seem like a stretch to say that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are essentially the same function - multiplication by a number - just in different settings. So maybe there is some more abstract setting where we can rewrite them as the same object to put the equality in genuinely commutative terms. And with properties $2-4,$ we no longer can simply put $f$ in both sides, however we can replace it on the RHS with a higher arity version of the same function. i.e $2$ can be expressed as $f_1 \circ g_1 = g_2 \circ f_2$ where we have
$g_1((x_n),(y_n)) = (x_n + y_n)$ and $g_2(L_1,L_2) = L_1 + L_2$, which is the same sort of relationship as before, they are both essentially addition, but now we have $f_1(x_n) =$ lim$(x_n)$ and $f_2((x_n),(y_n)) = (\text{lim}(x_n),$lim$(y_n))$. So again maybe we would have commutativity if we could consider $f_1$ and $f_2$ “the same” object in some more abstract sense.
Am I on the right track that there is some way to articulate this pattern as a form of commutativity? If so how exactly is that done in a general way, applicable not just to $1-4$ but to things like linear transformations? If this isn’t commutativity, how do we describe what is going on here?

Sorry, not sure what you are asking.  Obviously it is of interest when two operations, not sure you mean functions, commute.  Is that your question?

@lulu No, my question is, since this pattern intuitively seems like an instance of commutativity, how do we write these equalities precisely in a way that reflects that?

What pattern is that?  Your post goes on and on.  Can you try to reduce it ?  I thought you were speaking of the commutativity of some operations.  Did you mean something else?

Equations like $f\circ g_1=g_2\circ f$ appear in category theory, where we talk about "commutative diagrams".

In the case of limits (say of sequences of real number for example) compatibility with multiplication by a scalar, addition and product would be resumed as saying that it is an algebra morphism between the algebra of sequences of real numbers admitting a limit and the reals seen as a real algebra. That would be the notion of morphism, a "function" that preserve the "structure" among two "similar" object. I am being vague on purpose but you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism for a more detailed explaination.
In much more general context, when the "structures" of the two objects are different, I think that what you might be trying to pinpoint could be the notion of functoriality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). It is the idea that certain "operations" are compatible with those "structures". The formalisation and study of such phenomena is done in a field called category theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).
